# Typings on a createInstance-like function

Tags: typescript

I'm unsure how to phrase this question, but it's probably best described through example. If I've got a factory function like this...

```
function createInstance<TConstructor>(ctor: TConstructor) {
    return new ctor();
}
```

Is there a way I can type this function so, for example if I:

```
class A {
    myProp: string;
};
const a = createInstance(A);
```

Then the type of `a` will automatically be inferred as an instance of A?

```
const a = createInstance(A);
a.myProp = 'Like so';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a construct signature.

```
type NoArgumentConstructor<T> = new () => T;
function createInstance<T>(ctor: NoArgumentConstructor<T>): T {
    return new ctor();
}

class A {
    myProp: string;
};

/* const a: A */
const a = createInstance(A);
```